# Is it possible to syntethize this Voltage Transfer Function?

Tags: transfer-function, theory, laplace-transform, synthesis, signal-theory

I have the following voltage transfer function:

$$ 
H(s) =  \frac {a s^4 + b s^2 + c}{p s^4 + q s^2 + r}
$$

Where \$a, b, c, p, q, r\$ are all real constants.

The only method I have been taught to synthesize transfer functions depends upon the denominator being a Hurtwiz polynomial, which in this case it is not.

Can this transfer function be synthesized at all, and if so, what method should I look up to?

Comment: It's been a long time, but doesn't the denominator need to have more zeroes than the numerator?

Comment: @Hearth : not for a,b,p,q = 0, c,r = 1 so not in general. (Beyond that, it's been a long time for me too!)

Comment: By my understanding, yes, the denominator should be a grade greater than the numerator. If both numerator and denominator have the same grade, there are still ways to solve this, but they depend on the denominator being a Hurtwitz polynomial. But I don't know if this alone is enough to say that the TF can't be synthesized or if there is another method to solve this?

Comment: @arevalo A [Hurwitz polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_polynomial) has the roots in the left-side of the complex plane. Since you don't give any values for the constants you can't say that it isn't a Hurwitz polynomial, because you don't know the roots. When you'll know them you'll be able to factor out the transfer function into two 2nd order stages. Or you could do it symbolically, but then you'll have to separate the roots that can make a Hurwitz polynomial from their counterparts (4th order means 4 roots), which means the transfer function will reduce to a 2nd order.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen polynomials having only even powers are special in some way. They may never be Hurwitz. I will try to get a source. But see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2239311).

Comment: @AJN Yes, that's why added the second part, where I mention breaking the transfer function. OP's question is a bit fuzzy to me: it's either dealing with a 4th order transfer function, or extracting the 2nd order transfer function from a 4th order. I tend to favour the latter (precisely because of the explanation in the link you provided), but that would be my interpretation -- it would be nice if OP clarified this.

Comment: I am not sure what OP means by synthesising. May be OP can add the method that they already know into the question so that we can see why it won't work for the given transfer function.

Comment: @AJN What I mean by synthesizing is to make up a circuit for the given TF. The method I have been taught consists of expressing the TF by the admittance values of the quadripole as: H(s) = - Y21 / (Y22 + 1 / RL). Then, the if the denominator is a Hurtwitz polynomial P(s), you can divide it in its even and odd parts: M(s) and N(s). If the numerator is a Q(s), dividing both numerator and denominator by M(s) and N(s) you can find the admittance values Y22 = N(s) / M(s) ; Y21 = -Q(s) / M(s). Sorry I can't find any online source that explains this better.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen The denominator can be seen as a [biquadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function). So, if z = s² then P(s) = p s⁴ + q s² + r = p z² + q z + r. And the roots can be s1 = sqrt(z1), s2 = - sqrt(z1), s3 = sqrt(z2), s4 = - sqrt(z2) where z1 and z2 are the roots of the quadratic equation: z1 = [-q+sqrt(q² - 4pr)]/2p and z2 = [-q-sqrt(q² - 4pr)]/2p.

Comment: I would not be surprised if non Hurwitz transfer function requires active elements like opamps for realisation. From your comment, you seem to be using only passive components. Are you using only passive components in the method you already use?? That might explain need for Hurwitz.

Comment: @AJN Exactly, that method is based on RLC components. I don't know of any other method using OAs for the realization.

Comment: Then the current posted answer would be the place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is realizable, convert the transfer function to state space:

[image]
Source: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2463007/if-a-state-space-realization-a-b-c-d-is-minimal-will-its-inverse-also-be-m

There are many forms you could then realize (cascade, canonincal, and parallel, I chose canonical), it will look like this, but with an additional integrator (with a w with four flyspecks), and \$a_3\$ term \$b_3\$ term

[image]
Source: [Basics of State Space Modeling UW Canvas](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcanvas.uw.edu%2Fcourses%2F1064526%2Ffiles%2F39431951%2Fdownload%3Fdownload_frd%3D1&psig=AOvVaw3fVypSV3DFgbDMdOTmj97s&ust=1623341347563000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCKj8upT4ivECFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD)

If you wanted to *physically realize this* you could do with opamps with the above form (which may not be the best use of components or dynamic range), each 1/s would be an integrator and each constant would be a gain (or gain stage). For the summation points you would need a summing amplifier. Keep in mind since some of your constants are zero you would not need a wire.

Whatever system you realize, you will need at least four integrators.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment

Answer (score 1):

I mean to write this as a comment but it ended up too long. Since you don't give *numeric* values to the coefficients then you can only solve this symbolically. As you correctly say in your [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/570274/is-it-possible-to-syntethize-this-voltage-transfer-function?noredirect=1#comment1491931_570274) (and as I hinted at [earlier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/570274/is-it-possible-to-syntethize-this-voltage-transfer-function?noredirect=1#comment1491917_570274)) that particular transfer function will give 4 roots: two positive and two negative. Since you need the Hurwitz polynomial, you'll need to select the negative ones, which means the whole transfer function reduces to a denominator of 2nd degree. That will mean you'll also have to adjust the numerator, too, since otherwise it will not be a proper transfer function. Whatever roots you will choose it won't matter towards the overall stability, but the order needs to be reduced to be at most equal to the denominator.

Mathematically, you'll have this:

$$\begin{align}
D(s)&=ps^4+qs^2+r \tag{1} \\
s_{1,2,3,4}&=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{-q\pm\sqrt{q^2-4pr}}{2p}} \tag{2} \\
D_{1,2}(s)&=s^2-\dfrac{\sqrt{q^2-4pr}}{2p}+\dfrac{q}{2p} \tag{3} \\
D_{3,4}(s)&=s^2+\dfrac{\sqrt{q^2-4pr}}{2p}+\dfrac{q}{2p} \tag{4} \\
\end{align}$$

In the comments you also say that you need to synthesize this as a passive network (this should have been in the OP), so then this is where you got stuck. Can you take it from here?